# Google Cloud SQL - CPU utilization more than doubled after upgrade

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We have recently **upgraded our MySQL** database in Google Cloudfrom 8.0.26 **to 8.0.33** and now we are seeing that the **CPU utilization went up from around 13% to roughly 30%**.
I am not aware of any other change that could cause this (other than the MySQL upgrade).
The server is statistically receiving the same amount of queries (of the same type) than before.

Parameters of the DB server:

```
vCPUs: 1
Memory: 5 GB
SSD storage: 10 GB
Region: europe-west1-b (Belgium)
```

I am attaching graphs from the database server "System insights" page (you can see the CPU utilization on the first picture, in the top-left graph, the upgrade happaned around 29th of June):

## Pic 1

[image: graph_1]

## Pic 2

[image: graph_2]

## Pic 3

[image: graph_3]

## Pic 4

[image: graph_4]

## Pic 5

[image: graph_5]

## Pic 6

[image: graph_6]

Any idea what could have caused this and how to find out why has it happened? I expected improvements when upgrading the database server and not degraded performance :/

Comment: CPU -- Perhaps one query is being performed differently.  Let's locate the slow query with the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) .  The monitoring plugin you are using may include such.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide CPU busy relief suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck STATUS command does now exist in our MySQL: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'STATUS' at line 1

Comment: @WilsonHauck A) https://justpaste.it/5b0vu B) https://jpst.it/3ia-H C) https://jpst.it/3ib1e D) https://jpst.it/3ib1I E) command 'STATUS;' not found G) https://jpst.it/3ib1X

Comment: The commands were meant to be run with a semicolon following the request rather than a colon.  I will deal with it here.  Suggestions will be delayed.

Comment: @RickJames unfortunately the slow log is not enabled. I will try to enable it though and check the output. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @scr4bble  When you enable the Slow Query Log, please also, 

long_query_time=1   # from 10 second long query time limit and 

see if you can  

log_slow_extra=ON  #from OFF to make the slow query log more helpful.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I suggest adding `AND Data_free > 8e6` to avoid non-partitioned tables that won't shrink.  (That test is inadequate for Partitioned tables.)  (I guess it was marked "abusive" due to the bolding.)

Comment: @scr4bble - What were the "log entries"?

Comment: Plain `STATUS;` works in the mysql commandline tool.  It is probably redundant and can be ignored.

Comment: Please don't use the JSON format for the SHOWs.  I can process virtually any other format.

Comment: A) looks like about 1.4GB total.  That is rather trival.  And yet 33% Disk utilization??

Comment: @RickJames the Cloud SQL is managed service that increases the storage as the data grows. Sorry for the JSONs - I will use CSV next time. The issue just got solved during the maintenance triggered by Google. I am trying to find out what has changed so I can post the information here. Let me know if you have ideas how to check this out - I probably cannot expect Google to respond to my questions what did they do during the maintenance since we don't have the dedicated support package.

Comment: So, first finding is that there is a new variable now: "force_ssl_for_tcp": set to value "NONE". The variable wasn't present before. Another change is "version_compile_zlib": changed from "1.2.13" to "1.2.13.1".
Could this make any difference?

Comment: I guess it might rather have been some change on the server where the MySQL is being run? Wondering how likely is it that the change/fix actually came from anything MySQL related. Becuase zlib version got upgraded, I expect this was a server/machine/OS update that might have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your summary of tables, data, index and free space used indicates some tables are fragmented and need to be OPTIMIZE'd to reduce unnecessary overhead.

Please run this query,

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') DATA_Space, CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space, create_time, table_rows, engine, create_options
from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') and Data_free > ( DATA_length * .1) ORDER BY FLOOR ( FREE_Space ) DESC, FLOOR ( DATA_Space ) DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME LIMIT 0,512 ;

For each table listed, OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_name;

Suggestions to consider for reducing cpu utilization in your Google Database Options configuration,

```
max_connections=1024  # from 4030 - if you can make this change
read_rnd_buffer_size=16382  # from 262144 to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 311
read_buffer_size=393216  # from 131072 to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 523
table_open_cache_instances=1  # from 16 - you only have 1 CORE available
innodb_parallel_read_threads=1  # from 4 - you only have 1 CORE available
```

Observations to consider,

A) com_begin had 3382 and com_commit had 13 in 11 days.
Usually this indicates someone forgot the needed commit to free resources ASAP.

B) com_unlock_tables had 1,423,489 events in 11 days.  Most systems we have analyzed have not found this to be necessary.

C) handler_rollback recorded 3,371 events in 11 days.  Average 1 every 5 minutes.
Rollbacks are expensive in use of resources.
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON  will reveal the queries finding rollback necessary.

D) log_error is reported as stderr.  Most instances use /mysql/logs/error.log for the filename.  You really do need an error log - that can be viewed for analysis.

E) I see all your filenames are using unusual naming convention of
'backslash'/folder'backslash'/folder'backslash'/filename
never seen the backslash used in this manner for an instance.
There are several in your SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES list of values.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will go over them in the next days.
I just found out that the CPU utilization went back down to the previous levels today + it doesn't oscilate so much anymore. I went into Operations log and found out there was a maintenance that ran exactly at the same time when the issue got fixed so I expect the maintenance fixed it (triggered by Google, not me). I will try to find out what has changed during the maintenance and I will post the information here.

Comment: Our suggestions and observations are still valid and need to be considered, AFTER stop/start 11 days of uptime to see if any of the bad ratios have been reduced.